# Error while saving data in MongoDB atlas with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save data in the MongoDB atlas with node.js and mongoose.

Every time I use `MySchema.save()`, Data is inserting But I'm also getting the error:

> `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'majority;' found in replica set configuration`

Also, there is no duplicate entry, Data is also inserting But I'm also getting the error

```js
let User = require('../models/users.models');

const username = req.body.username;
const newUser = new User({username});
newUser.save()
.then(() => res.json('user added!'))
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
```

**User model**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    username:  {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 3
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 59):

I know it was asked 2 months ago, but for those who will encounter the same issue. 
You are mistakenly entering a wrong char at the end of the URI string: 
`mongodb+srv://${ user }:${ password }@track-mkahl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority;`
You need to delete the `;` after the word `majority`.

Comment: I love you here is a kiss from me

Comment: yes thanks, for some reason i had a white space at the end of string and it caused the same error

Comment: Copy-pasters (including me) be like .......dammnnnnnn

Comment: @SarveshDalvi I was not able to find this line again on their docs, can you post a link here plz?

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/connect-to-your-cluster/ . You can find this implementation on 6th point : "Connect with sample app", where that URI format is present. If you need the URI specific for your project then you can go to your atlas dashboard, go the overview tab just below your cluster name and click on the connect option at the right corner. Then select "connect your application" from the pop up. There you can find the code to connect your cluster to your node js program including the URI.

Comment: @SarveshDalvi Thanks :)

Comment: This should be set as a correct answer...I had "; at the end and was causing problems.

Comment: The semicolon right after the value in a .env variable becomes part of its value.

Answer (score 6):

This helped me.

```js
const schema = new Schema({ name: String }, {
  writeConcern: {
    w: 'majority',
    j: true,
    wtimeout: 1000
  }
});
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#writeConcern

Answer (score 5):

```
"mongoURI" : "mongodb+srv://${ user }:${ password }@cluster0.mde0j.mongodb.net/cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority "
```

I get the same error with this in default.json its simple error just delete the `&w=majority` part at the end and it will be solved

Answer (score 1):

for me it was also in the URI string like @Yossi Saadi has suggested, it's just that I had `majoritys` written there instead of `majority`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with this line.

> let User = require('../models/users.models');

I have created a solution for you.

> /models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/stack-overflow", { useNewUrlParser: true })

var userSchema = new Schema({
    username:  {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 3
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User
```

> /routes/userroute.js

```
const User = require("../models/user")
// Imagine run() as an asynchronous request handler
async function run() {
    try {
        const user1 = new User({ username: "lidafafnus" })
        user1.save((err,result) => {
            console.log(err, result)
        })
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
} 

run()
```