# i am getting this error in postman"UnknownReplWriteConcern",

Tags: postman

```
{
    "code": 79,
    "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
    "errInfo": {
        "writeConcern": {
            "w": "majority;",
            "wtimeout": 0,
            "provenance": "clientSupplied"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "n": 1,
        "opTime": {
            "ts": {
                "$timestamp": "7022355027419201549"
            },
            "t": 99
        },
        "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000063",
        "ok": 1,
        "writeConcernError": {
            "code": 79,
            "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
            "errmsg": "No write concern mode named 'majority;' found in replica set configuration",
            "errInfo": {
                "writeConcern": {
                    "w": "majority;",
                    "wtimeout": 0,
                    "provenance": "clientSupplied"
                }
            }
        },
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": {
                "$timestamp": "7022355027419201549"
            },
            "signature": {
                "hash": "r4QJwdZlD6X28hYUeg3kkVrI7uw=",
                "keyId": {
                    "low": 1,
                    "high": 1620408145,
                    "unsigned": false
                }
            }
        },
        "operationTime": {
            "$timestamp": "7022355027419201549"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57179043/9569049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this at the end of Mongo URL and it worked ->>>> "&wtimeoutMS=5000";

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Found I had an extra set of single quotes around my db url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and put this code which contain ( writeConcern ) in my schema  and it works

```
const schema = new Schema({
   name: String
}, {
   writeConcern: {
      w: 'majority',
      j: true,
      wtimeout: 1000
   }
});
```

Another thing I did I removed a quote that was around the URL of the database:

Check out this link: https://pretagteam.com/question/mongowriteconcernerror-no-write-concern-mode-named-majority-found-in-replica-set-configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@<yourClouster>/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

review that your conexion not have " or ' or ; in the final

Answer (score 0):

if u have the same problem ,check your mongo db url.by mistakenly I've put a '/' at the end.Always be careful about urls

Answer (score 0):

// Use this code where you are connecting mongoose. This code will definitely work.
mongoose.connect(DB,{
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
writeConcern: {
w: 'majority',
j: true,
wtimeout: 1000
}
})

// for more queries reach out to alizahid069@gmail.com
//Thank You :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this one inside your connection. It worked for me.

```
mongoose.connect(
  DB,
  { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    writeConcern: { 
      w: 'majority', 
      j: true, 
      wtimeout: 1000 
    } 
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

"mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.jza7rkj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority/dbname"

and then i removed the dbname from the last of the url

"mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.jza7rkj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"