# Why am I getting a "400: Bad Request" but the request successfully posts to my DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am not sure what is happening. I had all the same code setup in dev using localhost and everything was working fine. I hosted my app to Vercel and my API to heroku and from what I can tell the API is working perfectly. The issue now is when I make a post request I get a 400 Bad Request error in the browser but it still makes the request and posts to my DB I have setup. Any help can be appreciated. I built this application in a MERN stack with NEXT.js

Here is my client side Post request

```
const postSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const { data } = await axios.post('/create-post', { content, image });
            
            if(data.error) {
                toast.error(data.error);
            } else {
                setPage(1);
                newsFeed();
                toast.success("Post created");
                setContent('');
                setImage({});
                // socket.emit('new-post', data);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Here is my server side handling of the post request

```
export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const { content, image } = req.body;
    if(!content.length) {
        return res.json({
            error: 'Content is required'
        })
    }

    try {
        const post = new Post({ content, image, postedBy: req.user._id });
        await post.save();

        const postWithUser = await Post.findById(post._id).populate('postedBy', '-password -secret');

        res.json(postWithUser);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
};
```

And here is what the browser is telling me

[Chrome Browser Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCZhQ.png)

Comment: What does `console.log(e)` in your server-side logs show?

Comment: [server logs][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB99s.png

Comment: #ReadTheError - looks like Mongo is not happy, and this is being propigated as an error. The write may be happening, but it's producing a `WriteConcern` for the reason described. Check your parameters in configuration, looks like you might be missing a comma somewhere.

Comment: Looks like I had extra characters at the end of my .env DATABASE variable. I appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a typo on the MongoDB connection string (URI), similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58459101/2075151).

In the linked answer, the typo was the semi-colon in `&w=majority;`. In your case, the value is somehow `majorityDATABASE=`, so double-check your MongoDB connection string and try to remove the extra `DATABASE=` in the write concern parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the `await Post.findById()` call is not finding a result which could be throwing an error when you try to call `res.json(postWihUser)`. That would then cause an error when `postWithUser` is not defined.

What is logged to the server's terminal when an error occurs? That should help you identify the problem.

Comment: The server responds with the correct req.body

But the try is failing with some MongoDB errors. (to long to post the whole console log) What I am not understanding is how my get requests are working fine and communicating with the DB but my POST is not.

Comment: [server logs][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB99s.png

Comment: Looks like I had extra characters at the end of my .env DATABASE variable. I appreciate the help on this.